# Touchpad stops working sometimes on thinkpad t410

Tags: touchpad

My touchpad stops working accidentally, what can be the problem? only rebooting helps.

Comment: same with me what could be possible reason I use Dell Inspiron 1550  with Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1):

In 11.10 there was a problem with the daemon which disabled the touchpad when typing.  I *think* this should have been resolved and certainly isn't a problem in 12.04.

In general though, including for 12.04, there are problems with the touchpad and trackpoint misbehaving on Thinkpads in recent years.  There are a few workarounds.

One is to add the `i8042.reset=Y` kernel parameter.  e.g.:

```
sudo /bin/sed -i 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="[^"]*/\0 i8042.reset=Y /' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

... and reboot.  This makes the serial driver responsible for the trackpoints more inclined to reset itself, and seems to improve reliability.

If you have problems with the trackpoint disappearing after suspend, then the psmouse-suspend-modules package from ppa:jamesf/lenovofixes will make the system reload the relevant driver after suspend, which resolves a few issues.  i.e.:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jamesf/lenovofixes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psmouse-suspend-modules
```